# Why does vim fail with multi-line edits with a period under the cursor?

Tags: vim, comments

I've had the issue for a while now where if I try and do a multiline edit starting with a period ('.') under the cursor (e.g. multi-line comment for a chain of Javascript function calls), the operation fails and only the first line gets the comment. A sample block would look like this:

```
d3.select(this).append("text")
  .attr("class", name)
  .attr("dy", dy)
  .style("fill", "black")
```

If I try and comment out lines 2-4 inclusive at the same time with the cursor starting at the '.' in 'attr', only that line gets the comment.

The commands being used to do multi-line commenting is first using Ctrl+V to enter visual mode, highlighting the relevant lines using j/k, then initiating the multi-line insert using shift+I.

I imagine it's to do with the the period having some special significance, but what is it, and how would I bypass it in this use case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which command or keystroke do you use for commenting ?

Comment: Visual mode using Ctrl+V first, highlighting the lines to be commented, then shift+I to do the multi-line insert. I'll add this information to the question as well

Comment: Try do it with `vim -u NONE`. You will see that it works without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Meninx-メネンックス. You were right - I'll have a look through my vimrc to see what's causing the behaviour.

Comment: Try do it with `vim --noplugin` if you encounter the problem than start fetching `.vimrc` otherwise this is a problem of plugins probably.

Comment: Turns out that the cause of the problem was a jsx plugin, even with --noplugin enabled. After disabling this line in my vimrc (in neovim, not that that's important here) in --noplugin mode: `let g:jsx_ext_required = 0`, the problem was no longer.

Comment: Happy to help !